# Can you substitute equivalent powers?

Tags: modular-arithmetic, congruences

Sorry for the rather vague title, but I don't know how to phrase it. My question is: if a ≡ b (mod m), may i substitute b wherever a is used as a power? i.e., if I have 4^(105), where my modulus is 105, may I say 4^105 ≡ 4^0 = 1 (mod 105)?

Comment: No, that doesn't work. In this example, we have $4^{105} \equiv 4 \pmod{5}$, and hence $4^{105} \not\equiv 4^0 \pmod{105}$. In exponents, if the base is coprime to the modulus, you can reduce modulo the totient of the modulus. Here, we have $\varphi(105) = 2 \cdot 4 \cdot 6 = 48$, so $4^{105} \equiv 4^9 \pmod{105}$, since $105 \equiv 9 \pmod{48}$.

Answer (score 1):

no, you cant, as $2^3=8 \equiv 2 \not\equiv 1=2^0 \pmod  3$

However, with Fermat's small theorem, if $p$ is prime,$n^p \equiv n\pmod p$
so if $a \equiv b\pmod  p$ and $x \equiv y\pmod{ \color{red}{p-1}}$, then $a^x \equiv b^y\pmod p$

Comment: thank you! i appreciate the tip!

Comment: The LaTeX for mod is `\pmod`, so that `$x\pmod y$` becomes $x\pmod y$.

Comment: @AkivaWeinberger Thanks!